# How to replace whitespaces by a plus "+" sign

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

hey all i want a code the replace whitespaces by a + sign in objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace multiple characters in a string in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case you are asking this because you need to encode URLs, use this

```
NSString* escapedUrlString =
  [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If you just need space to +, use

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return [thatString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

If your real target is to escape URL component, use the `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method instead.