# Variable is not a CFString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting value from JSON it gives exception var is not CFString.
   below is the link from which i am getting data
     http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=categories&appid=620&mainonly=true

`NSString *test = aBook.catId`;

Book Class

```
@interface Book : NSObject {


NSString *catId;


NSString *name;
```

}

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString*catId;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;

 @end





    #import "Book.h"


    @implementation Book


    @synthesize catId,name;


  -(id)init{

  self=[super init];

    }

   - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dict {


self.catId = [dict valueForKey:@"categoryId"];
self.name =  [dict valueForKey:@"name"];




      return self;



      }

   - (void)dealloc {
   [catId release];
   [name release];
   [super dealloc];
   }


   @end
```

Comment: If that is not a string that can be some other object like *NSNumber*.

Comment: It is not string so you have to do casting to store it in string

Comment: Use [NSString stringWithFormat:]

Answer (score 0):

Its an integer maybe. Use this.

```
   NSString* test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aBook.catId];
```

Comment: its giving wrong value using this can you pleas check the json data in which catid is given so that you can get idea to store that

Comment: print the value of aBook.catId using NSLog(@"%@",aBook.catId) and let me know what it comes.

Comment: { "categoryId": 202, "name": "Sport" } cat id is given in this way and i am storing it in NSString

Comment: can you post the code about how you are giving value to aBook.catId?

Comment: its because you have declared the catId as NSString. in the header file declare catId as NSInteger and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question should help you

[Replace multiple characters in a string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c)

```
CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)aNSString;
```

works perfectly and transparently. Likewise:

```
NSString *aNSString = (NSString *)aCFString;
```