# Variable is not a CFString error showing

Tags: iphone

I am getting value from JSON it gives exception var is not CFString. below is the link from which i am getting data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question should help you

[Replace multiple characters in a string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c)

```
CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)aNSString;
```

works perfectly and transparently. Likewise:

```
NSString *aNSString = (NSString *)aCFString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the class of you var using [var isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], if it returns true then assign it to your string variable.