# Saving files with slash in file name - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, filesystems

I can't save file with slash in file name. I download file, and if file has slash in the name, it doesn't want to save. For example full name of the song: "H/F ArtistName - Song name.mp3". Is it possible to save files with slash in name? Or how to properly replace slash?

Answer (score 2):

From another post:

```
    NSString *s = @"foo/bar:baz.foo";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s); // => foobarbazfoo
```

[or just look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

/ is generally used as a separator between files or folders in the operating system. therefore the filename can not contain a slash as that would confuse the H in the name for a folder.

The best idea is to replace it with a whitespace or simple delete it to give: "HF ArtistName - Songname.mp3"

Comment: Try entering slash in filename on MacOSX. It does not matter what is used as separator until file components are properly escaped.

Comment: The various Mac/Apple filesystems do not use slash ("/") as the separator, they use colon (":"). So a file or directory can contain slash but cannot contain colon. In the various interfaces (eg terminal, shells) slash, the POSIX directory separator, is used but can be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

Xcode 12.3, iOS 14

```
fileName.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: ":") //  just have a try...
```

full demo code:

```
public extension Data {
    func saveToTemporaryDirectory(fileName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void)  {

        var localURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        localURL.appendPathComponent(fileName.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: ":"))

        do {
            try self.write(to: localURL)
            completionHandler(.success(localURL))
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        }

    }
}
```