# Remove characters from string iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding, character

I have an XML which I am using to parse news. News have a description. I'm using `NSString` to show that description in `UILabel`.

But, the description comes like this:

```
Bad news for Windows&#8217; the researches show that Windows&#8217; for years....
```

And it is being showed with those unwanted characters in `UILabel`. The numbers are changing in every string. They are not the sames.

I want to remove the characters that begins with `&#` and the numbers that follow. How can I do that? Which string encoding format should I use?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I don't have just one string. If I remove &#8217 from this one, there might be &#7610 in another one. It won't be removed.

I can remove &# characters and numbers too. But when I do that, In a string like that "In 1980, Jobs told us to&#2540 do something" the output will be "In , Jobs told us to do something" 1980 will be gone too, but I don't want that. That's a problem either.

Comment: For a hint, you need to specify the regular expression pattern and check the range of string is present in your string and remove that string..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2560488/1730272

Comment: ... or `stringByDecodingXMLEntities` in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453142/1187415.

Answer (score 2):

These are ASCAII symbols so you need to use utf-8 string.check this [link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

so use this line of code

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myAsciiString];
```