# How to remove double quotes and brackets from NSString

Tags: ios, string

I have string in this from `["658681","655917","655904"]`i want to change this string in this form `658681,655917,655904` how it can be changed? below is my code of string

```
- (IBAction)Searchbtn:(id)sender {

    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:getmessageIDArray options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    _finalIDStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the final ID Str==%@",_finalIDStr);



}
```

Comment: Try using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` of `NSString` or refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c

Comment: Double _colon_ would be `::`, presumably you mean the double quote `"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520752/how-to-remove-double-quotes-and-brackets-from-nsstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code:

```
NSCharacterSet *unwantedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"[]"];
NSString *requiredString = [[_finalIDStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unwantedChars] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

It's efficient and effective way to remove as many characters from your string in one single line..

Comment: A down vote without comment is a coward way of abusing some one. I want to see better solution/answer from the person who is giving down votes..

Comment: Just use the above mentioned code and if doesn't work go for other solution. BTW it will work..

Comment: It's the best solution here.

Answer (score 6):

this will do it in swift

```
var stringwithoutquotes = string1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
var removebracket1 = stringwithoutquotes.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "")
var removebracket2 = removebracket1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "")
```

or you could do the entire thing in one line

```
var string2 = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "")
```

Here is another cleaner option in swift

```
var string = "\"hello[]" // string starts as "hello[]
var badchar: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\"[]")
var cleanedstring: NSString = (string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(badchar) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
//cleanedstring prints as "hello"
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let string = "\"hello[]" // string starts as "hello[]
let badchar = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\"[]")
let cleanedstring = string.components(separatedBy: badchar).joined()
//cleanedstring prints as "hello"
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4 (String Array)
I wanted to convert String Array into String text to be placed in TextView:

**FROM**
["horse","cat","dog"]

**TO**
horse
cat
dog

```
var stringArray = ["horse","cat","dog"]

var stringArrayCleaned = stringArray.description.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "\n").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")


print(stringArrayCleaned)
```

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
[[[_finalIDStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone is still looking for answer.. I achieved this in swift using `joined(separator:)` see: [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690077-joined)

```
var stringArray = ["alice","bob","cindy"]
print(stringArray.joined(separator: ","))

// this will print: alice,bob,cindy
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *str = ["658681","655917","655904"];
NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"[]"];
str = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Not going to work. This will look for the exact string *"[]* and will not find any occurence.

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed in answer.

Comment: Better, but your first line is still wrong. It will not create a string.

Comment: But you are clever enough to surround it with `@""` right?

Comment: SO doesn't have a build-in compiler. I think anyone can solve such simple errors I have made in answer. Focusing on that is not constructive.